# How can a surface charge create field on itself?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, electricity

How is the surface charge creating a field on itself ?Grifith has put me in confusion.The example 4.8 of electrodynamics by Grifith shows that the bound surface charge is partly due to the field of a nearby charge and partly due to the surface charge itself...He then shows that the field due to surface charge is $-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_{0}}$,when it could have been positive also(for me field is above and below but not at the surface)...please help me get out of this confusion...[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the paragraphs below Eq. 4.30, Griffiths remarks:

"Note that $\mathbf{E}$ in Eq. 4.30 is the *total* field; it may be due in part to free charges and in part to the polarization itself. If, for instance, we put a piece of dielectric into an external field $E_0$, we cannot compute $P$ directly from Eq. 4.30; the external field will polarize the material, and this polarization will produce its own field, which then contributes to the total field, and this in turn modifies the polarization, which . . . Breaking out of this infinite regress is not always easy."

Here you have exactly that- the electric field in the calculation requires the contribution from the point charge above the plane, and the bound charge on the plane $z = 0$.

The field from the bound surface charge $\frac{-\sigma_b}{2\epsilon_0}$ is negative because we're looking for the field inside the dielectric- below the surface.

Indeed the electric field is well defined above and below the plane $z = 0$, but is discontinuous on the plane *because* of the surface charge.

EDIT: Griffiths states "where $E_z$ is the $z$-component of the total field *just* inside the dielectric, at $z = 0$." In other words, yes we are looking at the field *inside* the dielectric, but are taking the limit $z\rightarrow 0_-$. In this way we can focus on the field at the boundary while technically still in the dielectric.

Comment: But they all are point functions..now p=εχE dictates that p at each point is proportional to the field at the same point...so similar is the case with σ=p.n.so why do we relate surface charge at surface to the field below it...shouldnt it be the field at the same point

Comment: @JazzKhan You are correct. We are looking at the field in the limit we approach the surface, from inside the dielectric. I've updated my answer to hopefully make this clearer.